# GetParent method to go up 2 levels

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the directory of my project folder using the following code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myPath = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location));

        Console.WriteLine(myPath);            
    }
```

as you can see, the code returns the executable path: ../PROJECT_FOLDER/bin/Debug's parent directory, therefore it returns ../PROJECT_FOLDER/bin.

I would like for it to only return ../PROJECT_FOLDER.

Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have just found the solution, hope it helps someone down the line:

```
var myPath = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)).ToString());

        Console.WriteLine(myPath);
```